# How to check whether a value is NaN and replace it with NULL?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
var a = ['1', '2', '3', '4', 'a', 'b', 'c']

c = a.map(x => Number(x));

console.log(c)
```

I want it to return `[ 1, 2, 3, 4, null, null, null]`
but it returns `[ 1, 2, 3, 4, NaN, NaN, NaN ]` for me.

Comment: Because `Number(someStringThatDoesntStartWithNumbers)` returns `NaN`

Comment: IsNaN(n) checks if a value is NaN. NaN is also the value that is not identical to itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the item with [`isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN), if *true* return *null* else convert to number:

```js
var a = ['1', '2', '3', '4', 'a', 'b', 'c']

c = a.map(x => isNaN(x) ? null : Number(x));

console.log(c)
```